# How to check whether text input is finished

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm developing a simple WPF application where I want to use the text changed method for a specific text field. the thing is I implemented the method but, the method gets fired in very short period, like even after i enter one character. I want to check whether the text change is completed in order to go with the methods written in the text changed method.

```
private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (...) // how to check whether the typing is finished?
    {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to predict whether the user is about to press another key?

Comment: actually m asking whether I can check the user has ended typing into the text box!

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need the `LostFocus` event for this.  As @SLaks comment says, you can't predict whether the user will press another key.  Alternatively, you could databind the control - depending on what you're actually trying to do that may make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `TextChanged`, try monitoring the `LostFocus` event, which will fire when the user has left the textbox, either through pressing Enter/Tab or clicking somewhere else on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with LostFocus

[UIElement.LostFocus Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus.aspx)

Question does not ask about binding but something to consider.
In binding the equivalent is UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"

[Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx)

With binding you can get into more advanced validation UI effects.

[How to: Implement Binding Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962.aspx)